# get html attribute value which attribute name include colon with xpath expression

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm using scrapy with selenium I have this html input element:

```
<input class="anniucssC" type="button" value="当页累计" v:click="doThisPageTtl()">
<input class="anniucssC" type="button" value="全部累计" v:click="doAllTtl()">
<input class="anniucssC" type="button" value="选择累计" v:click="doChoiceTtl()">
<input class="anniucssC" type="button" value="打印" v-click="showLayer('shadow123','question12
3');">
```

And I'm trying to get v:click's value with this Xpath expression:

**`//input[1]/@v:click`**

i got this error in xpath tester:

```
Unable to perform XPath operation. The prefix "v" for attribute "v:click" associated with an element type "input" is not bound.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the attribute value you can use the below logic.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input").get_attribute("v:click")
```

**xpath:** If you want to access all nodes with `v:click` attribute use this xpath.

```
//input[@*[name() = '@value']]
```

[image]

**CSS:** If you want to use any specify attribute along with value you can use this css.
    input[v:click='doAllTtl()']

Comment: i use the xpath expression: //input[@*[name() = ‘v:click']], but get the response data: data='<input class="anniucssC" type="button" value="当页累计" v''  ,the string after the colon is missing